# Transparent icon both svg or <i> tag with colored background

Tags: svg, background, icons, font-awesome, transparent

Here's my problem:

I have a section with some social icons. This section is within a wider div that has a background image. Now I want to give to each icon a rounded white background but I want to keep the icon transparent, so I will have a pleasant effect, but I don't want to do it with photoshop (png image) because it would be easier and actually is not my goal.

I want to do it with HTML, Font-Awesome, and CSS.

Here's my goal:

[image]

And here's my markup and css:

HTML:

```
<div class="splash-image">
    <div class="letterhead">
      <ul class="social">
        <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.splash-image {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
    background-image: url(../images/myimage.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 96vh;
    .letterhead {
        .social {
            li {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                background: white;
                i::before{
                    background:transparent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First of all: Is it doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're very dedicated to your mission of using just those techs then it's possible to use a filter and a green screen technique to accomplish your goal. But the result is a bit crispy & I'd recommend going with an SVG solution - it's what SVG is built for.

```css
body{
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501630834273-4b5604d2ee31?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
} 

.circle{
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 0.3em;
 font-size: 4em;
 }
 
.fa-twitter{
  background: white;
 color: red;
  padding: 0.15em 0.19em;
 }


.fa-facebook{
  background: white;
 color: red;
  padding: 0.13em 0.41em;
 }

.redknockout {
  filter: url(#red-knockout);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="fa fa-twitter circle redknockout"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook circle redknockout"></i>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="red-knockout">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
                     values="1 0 0 0 0 
                             0 1 0 0 0 
                             0 0 1 0 0 
                             -1 1 1 0 0"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Font-Awesome icons you can use svg. In SVG if you draw a path where a part is drawn clockwise and the other conter-clockwise you get a hole:

```css
body{background:gold}
```

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 26 26" width="100">  
      <path d="M0,0 L26,0 26,26 0,26 0,0 M21,5 5,5 5,21 21,21 21,5" />
    </svg>
```

The same way you can create in SVG a circle with a social icon hole:

```css
body{background:gold;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 26 26" width="30">
  <path d="M2,13A11,11 0 0 0 24,13A11,11 0 0 0 2,13
           M19.805,7.708
   c-0.334,0.446-0.667,0.892-1.022,1.365c0.403-0.106,0.822-0.216,1.24-0.326c0.019,0.023,0.036,0.047,0.055,0.07
   c-0.087,0.123-0.161,0.259-0.264,0.367c-0.331,0.353-0.784,0.642-0.98,1.056c-0.197,0.414-0.115,0.952-0.201,1.427
   c-0.103,0.558-0.215,1.12-0.392,1.658c-0.555,1.682-1.577,3.028-3.007,4.072c-0.75,0.549-1.583,0.949-2.468,1.178
   c-1.351,0.349-2.726,0.382-4.108,0.087c-0.786-0.167-1.515-0.448-2.216-0.823c-0.095-0.051-0.173-0.134-0.245-0.242
   c1.4-0.03,2.714-0.242,3.812-1.196c-1.171-0.268-2.009-0.871-2.437-2.066c0.319-0.03,0.593-0.056,0.868-0.082
   c-1.148-0.626-1.847-1.475-1.914-2.851c0.409,0.114,0.737,0.206,1.135,0.317c-0.312-0.437-0.594-0.764-0.801-1.133
   C6.407,9.781,6.45,8.941,6.788,8.107c0.08-0.197,0.199-0.271,0.386-0.058c0.839,0.958,1.839,1.723,3.03,2.167
   c0.796,0.297,1.65,0.439,2.483,0.63c0.042,0.01,0.17-0.164,0.187-0.265c0.077-0.449,0.081-0.915,0.198-1.351
   c0.218-0.806,0.782-1.369,1.526-1.683c1.085-0.458,2.146-0.341,3.084,0.407c0.294,0.233,0.562,0.205,0.866,0.086
  c0.378-0.148,0.756-0.295,1.135-0.443C19.723,7.635,19.764,7.672,19.805,7.708z"/></svg>
```

Comment: but how can we create the social icon in svg if I dont understande this code ?
It is possible to create a icon question mark ?

Comment: @nideba you can use this for the question mark `<svg width='30' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>live help</title>
<path d='M0,12A11,11 0 0 0 24,12A11,11 0 0 0 0,12M13,18H11V16H13V18ZM15.07,10.25L14.17,11.17C13.45,11.9,13,12.5,13,14H11V13.5C11,12.4,11.45,11.4,12.17,10.67L13.41,9.41C13.78,9.05,14,8.55,14,8C14,6.9,13.1,6,12,6S10,6.9,10,8H8C8,5.79,9.79,4,12,4S16,5.79,16,8C16,8.88,15.64,9.68,15.07,10.25Z'></path>
</svg>` - adapted from Google's SVG icons

Comment: can you send me a link from Google's SVG Icons ?

Comment: You can use this: [Google's SVGs](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/VKoqqG). Click the icon & get the SVG code from the console

Answer (score 1):

You can make the icon transparent using a mask. As a mask, the icon itself will be.
To make the body of the icon transparent it is necessary to fill it with black color `fill ="black"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1920 1200">
  <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
   <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  <path transform="scale(4) translate(10 35)"  d="M2,13A11,11 0 0 0 24,13A11,11 0 0 0 2,13
           M19.805,7.708
   c-0.334,0.446-0.667,0.892-1.022,1.365c0.403-0.106,0.822-0.216,1.24-0.326c0.019,0.023,0.036,0.047,0.055,0.07
   c-0.087,0.123-0.161,0.259-0.264,0.367c-0.331,0.353-0.784,0.642-0.98,1.056c-0.197,0.414-0.115,0.952-0.201,1.427
   c-0.103,0.558-0.215,1.12-0.392,1.658c-0.555,1.682-1.577,3.028-3.007,4.072c-0.75,0.549-1.583,0.949-2.468,1.178
   c-1.351,0.349-2.726,0.382-4.108,0.087c-0.786-0.167-1.515-0.448-2.216-0.823c-0.095-0.051-0.173-0.134-0.245-0.242
   c1.4-0.03,2.714-0.242,3.812-1.196c-1.171-0.268-2.009-0.871-2.437-2.066c0.319-0.03,0.593-0.056,0.868-0.082
   c-1.148-0.626-1.847-1.475-1.914-2.851c0.409,0.114,0.737,0.206,1.135,0.317c-0.312-0.437-0.594-0.764-0.801-1.133
   C6.407,9.781,6.45,8.941,6.788,8.107c0.08-0.197,0.199-0.271,0.386-0.058c0.839,0.958,1.839,1.723,3.03,2.167
   c0.796,0.297,1.65,0.439,2.483,0.63c0.042,0.01,0.17-0.164,0.187-0.265c0.077-0.449,0.081-0.915,0.198-1.351
   c0.218-0.806,0.782-1.369,1.526-1.683c1.085-0.458,2.146-0.341,3.084,0.407c0.294,0.233,0.562,0.205,0.866,0.086
  c0.378-0.148,0.756-0.295,1.135-0.443C19.723,7.635,19.764,7.672,19.805,7.708z"/>
  </mask>
  </defs> 
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpeqF.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)"/> 
   
  </svg>
```

Comment: Very nice solution! However I would have used a smaller viewBox, something like `2 2 22 22`  and I would have made the image a DOM element

Comment: @ enxaneta Thank you!. I added an image inside svg to make it responsive to any gadget.